# Oracle SQL Developer : Error Unknown Command (CHECK)

Tags: xcode, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Can anyone tell me why my check code is giving me a error of 
Error report:
Unknown Command

Below is my code for the table

```
PROMPT 'Creating Table property'
CREATE TABLE tp_property
(
    propertyid      NUMBER(20)   NOT NULL,
    landlordroleid      NUMBER(20)   NOT NULL,
    address         VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    city            VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
    state           CHAR(2)      NOT NULL,
    zipcode         VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    county          VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    schooldistrict      VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    yearbuilt           CHAR(4)      NOT NULL,
    numberofbeds        CHAR(4)      NOT NULL,
    numberofbaths       CHAR(4)      NOT NULL,
    numberofrooms       CHAR(4)      NOT NULL,
    petsallowed         CHAR(1),
    onsiteparking           CHAR(1),     
    inunitlaundry           CHAR(1),     
    propertype      VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT tp_property_PK PRIMARY KEY ( propertyid ) ) ;

ALTER TABLE tp_property
ADD CONSTRAINT  tp_property_FK FOREIGN KEY (landlordroleid)
    REFERENCES  tp_landlordrole(landlordroleid);

CONSTRAINT tp_property_CK CHECK (state IN ('NY', 'NJ', 'PA' ) ;

PROMPT Creating Index 'tp_property_I'
CREATE INDEX tp_property_I ON tp_property
 ( landlordroleid );

PROMPT 'Creating Sequence tp_propertyid_seq for the tp_property table'
CREATE SEQUENCE tp_propertyid_seq START WITH 0 MINVALUE 0 NOCACHE;
```

any suggestions are welcome thank you!

Comment: Your check constraint command is missing the ALTER TABLE ADD

Answer (score 1):

You've got 4 options I can think of, so - let's see them.

In order for the foreign key constraint not to fail, I'm creating a "dummy" LANDLORDROLE table:

```
SQL> create table tp_landlordrole (landlordroleid number primary key);

Table created.
```

### Option 1: inline constraints

```
SQL> create table tp_property
  2  (
  3      propertyid      number(20)   constraint tp_property_pk primary key,
  4      landlordroleid  number(20)   constraint tp_property_fk
  5                                     references tp_landlordrole (landlordroleid)
  6                                     not null,
  7      address         varchar2(50) not null,
  8      city            varchar2(15) not null,
  9      state           char(2)      constraint tp_property_ck
 10                                     check (state in ('NY', 'NJ', 'PA'))
 11                                     not null,
 12      zipcode         varchar2(10) not null,
 13      county          varchar2(20) not null,
 14      schooldistrict  varchar2(50) not null,
 15      yearbuilt       char(4)      not null,
 16      numberofbeds    char(4)      not null,
 17      numberofbaths   char(4)      not null,
 18      numberofrooms   char(4)      not null,
 19      petsallowed     char(1),
 20      onsiteparking   char(1),
 21      inunitlaundry   char(1),
 22      propertype      varchar2(10) not null
 23    );

Table created.

SQL>
```

### Option 2: out of line constraints

```
SQL> create table tp_property
  2  (
  3      propertyid      number(20),
  4      landlordroleid  number(20)   not null,
  5      address         varchar2(50) not null,
  6      city            varchar2(15) not null,
  7      state           char(2)      not null,
  8      zipcode         varchar2(10) not null,
  9      county          varchar2(20) not null,
 10      schooldistrict  varchar2(50) not null,
 11      yearbuilt       char(4)      not null,
 12      numberofbeds    char(4)      not null,
 13      numberofbaths   char(4)      not null,
 14      numberofrooms   char(4)      not null,
 15      petsallowed     char(1),
 16      onsiteparking   char(1),
 17      inunitlaundry   char(1),
 18      propertype      varchar2(10) not null,
 19      --
 20      constraint tp_property_pk primary key ( propertyid ) ,
 21      constraint tp_property_fk foreign key (landlordroleid)
 22        references tp_landlordrole (landlordroleid),
 23      constraint tp_property_ck check (state in ('NY', 'NJ', 'PA'))) ;

Table created.

SQL>
```

### Option 3: separate ALTER TABLE statements

```
SQL> create table tp_property
  2  (
  3      propertyid      number(20),
  4      landlordroleid  number(20)   not null,
  5      address         varchar2(50) not null,
  6      city            varchar2(15) not null,
  7      state           char(2)      not null,
  8      zipcode         varchar2(10) not null,
  9      county          varchar2(20) not null,
 10      schooldistrict  varchar2(50) not null,
 11      yearbuilt       char(4)      not null,
 12      numberofbeds    char(4)      not null,
 13      numberofbaths   char(4)      not null,
 14      numberofrooms   char(4)      not null,
 15      petsallowed     char(1),
 16      onsiteparking   char(1),
 17      inunitlaundry   char(1),
 18      propertype      varchar2(10) not null
 19  );

Table created.

SQL> alter table tp_property add constraint tp_property_pk
  2    primary key (propertyid);

Table altered.

SQL> alter table tp_property add constraint tp_property_fk
  2    foreign key (landlordroleid)
  3    references  tp_landlordrole(landlordroleid);

Table altered.

SQL> alter table tp_property add constraint tp_property_ck
  2    check (state in ('NY', 'NJ', 'PA')) ;

Table altered.

SQL>
```

### Option 4: a single ALTER TABLE statement

```
SQL> create table tp_property
  2  (
  3      propertyid      number(20),
  4      landlordroleid  number(20)   not null,
  5      address         varchar2(50) not null,
  6      city            varchar2(15) not null,
  7      state           char(2)      not null,
  8      zipcode         varchar2(10) not null,
  9      county          varchar2(20) not null,
 10      schooldistrict  varchar2(50) not null,
 11      yearbuilt       char(4)      not null,
 12      numberofbeds    char(4)      not null,
 13      numberofbaths   char(4)      not null,
 14      numberofrooms   char(4)      not null,
 15      petsallowed     char(1),
 16      onsiteparking   char(1),
 17      inunitlaundry   char(1),
 18      propertype      varchar2(10) not null
 19  );

Table created.

SQL> alter table tp_property
  2  add (constraint tp_property_pk primary key (propertyid),
  3       constraint tp_property_fk foreign key (landlordroleid)
  4         references tp_landlordrole(landlordroleid),
  5       constraint tp_property_ck
  6         check (state in ('NY', 'NJ', 'PA'))
  7      );

Table altered.

SQL>
```

Your unsuccessful attempt was somewhere between options 3 and 4, i.e. either you forgot the `alter table tp_property add`, or forgot to include the `constraint` clause into the previous `alter table` statement.

In some cases, you can combine the above options, but I'd suggest you to pick one in order to have it consistent. Inline constraints have a "drawback" - they can't contain more than a single column (for example, you can't create an inline composite primary key constraints).

For frequent drop/create purposes, I'd say that the 3rd option is the most flexible - create tables (without constraints) first, then add all constraints you need, one by one.

Finally, a few objections/suggestions, if I may.

- There's no need to specify `NOT NULL` for column(s) that make the primary key because primary key can't be `NULL` anyway.
- Re-think column data types; why did you use that many `CHARs`? They should be avoided (unless they really make sense - for example, for the STATE column, if it is always 2 characters long).
- Why did you use `CHAR` data type for "number of beds / rooms / baths"? I'd expect them to be `NUMBER`s, not strings.

More about [constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm) in Oracle documentation.